# dompdf - Problems with setBasePath() and chroot - setChroot()

Tags: dompdf

I updated dompdf from v0.8.3 to v2.0.0 and no style sheets are applied to my pdfs. I think it has something to do with the chroot directory, but honestly I don't understand the documentation regarding this.
I tried to simply my problems and gave you my basic file structure.

How do I have to set the chroot directory?

How can I apply multiple chroot directories, because I probably should not overwrite the default value (default is the root directory of the Dompdf library)?

Do I have to use setBasePath()? If I have to use it, how do I use it?

File-Structure:

```
myProject
├── application
│   ├── classes
│   │   ├── MyPdfClass.php
│   ├── library
│   │   ├── dompdf
│   │   │   ├── dompdf
│   │   │   │   ├── src
│   │   │   │   │   ├── Dompdf.php
├── htdocs
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── styles.css
│   ├── test.php
```

MyPdfClass.php:

```php
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;

class MyPdfClass extends Dompdf
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $options = new Options();
        $options->setChroot(???);
        $options->set('defaultPaperSize', 'A4');
        $options->set('defaultPaperOrientation', 'portrait');
        $options->set('defaultMediaType', 'screen');
        $options->set('defaultFont', 'Times');
        parent::__construct($options);
    }
}
```

test.php:

```php
$html = '<html>
            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/css/styles.css" />
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>TEST</h1>
            </body>
        </html>'

$pdf_obj = new MyPdfClass();
$pdf_obj->loadHtml($html);
$pdf_obj->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$pdf_obj->setBasePath(???);
$pdf_obj->render();
```